# Python: Create pdf figure from individual pdf figures based on their name; Matplotlib

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a single pdf figure from many individual pdf figures. I am generating many single pdf plots (graphs) into a folder. I need a way to view them all in a single figure (one pdf document with many graphs on it). The pdf files I generate have names based on two parameters. For example, files could be named:

```
red_1.pdf
red_5.pdf
red_10.pdf
blue_1.pdf
blue_5.pdf
blue_10.pdf
orange_1.pdf
orange_5.pdf
orange_10.pdf
```

I want a pdf figure that plots these pdf figures as a 2-axis chart (a grid of graphs located based on parameters in their name). My filename examples have a color and a number, I'd like the figure to have color on one axis and number on the other axis. All of the pdf flies are of the same dimensions. Any ideas?

Thanks All,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to create a pdf. But the following should write to a textfile, you would only have to add a part where the result is printed to a pdf.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files = os.listdir()
pdf_files = [i for i in files if i.endswith('.pdf')]
#pdf_files = [ 'orange_3.pdf','blue_4.pdf','green_10.pdf']

color,nr = [],[]

for fn in pdf_files:
    color += [fn.split('_')[0]]
    nr += fn.split('_')[1].strip('.pdf')

nms = range(len(color))
f = plt.figure()
plt.xticks(nms,color)
plt.scatter(color,nms)
plt.show()
f.savefig('fn.pdf')
```

Comment: I just realized that i might have misunderstood what you meant. Let me update again!

Comment: It didn't work. I got the following error message: 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: red'. Thanks for trying. The 'red' referred to the first component of the pdf name.

Comment: Hmm, and the `pdf_files` is a list of pdf files just like in the commented line?

Comment: It is. I verified that 'pdf_files' is a list of my pdf file names

Comment: ['e1q_1000.pdf',
 'e1q_10000.pdf',
 'e1q_2000.pdf',
 'e1q_5000.pdf',
 'e2q_1000.pdf',
 'e2q_10000.pdf',
 'e2q_2000.pdf',
 'e2q_5000.pdf',
 'e3q_1000.pdf',
 'e3q_10000.pdf',
 'e3q_2000.pdf',
 'e3q_5000.pdf']

Comment: I made up the colors to more easily lay out the question

Comment: On my system it works with the list that you just posted. Does it tell you the line in which it finds the error?

Comment: plt.scatter(color,nms)

Comment: I just realized I might be asking you something different. Each of my pdf files is an image. I want a single pdf image to view all of the single pdf images at once

Comment: Ah. My code gives you a scatterplot with the collors on one axis and the numbers on the other. Not what you need?

Comment: Not what I need. Thanks for trying. I need to make a pdf plot made up of a bunch of individual plots